# TFS release managment test result view fails with JSON error

Tags: integration-testing, ms-release-management

I have a TFS (on premises version 15.105.25910.0) server with build and release management definitions. One of the definitions deploys a web site, the test assemblies and then runs my MSTest based Selenium tests. Most pass, some are not run, and a few fail.

When I attempt to view the test results in the TFS web portal the view of "failed" test results fails and it shows the following error message:

> can't run your query: bad json escape sequence: \p. path
>   'build.branchname', line 1, position 182.

[image]

**Can anyone explain how this fault arises? or more to the point what steps I might take to either diagnose this further or correct the fault**

The troublesome environment and its "Run Functional Tests" task are shown below
[image]

**Attempted diagnostics**
As suggested by [Patrick-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5391065/patrick-msft) I added the requisite three steps to a build (the one that makes the selenium tests)

1. Windows machine file copy (Copy MStest assembly containing selenium test to c:\tests on a test machine)
2. Visualstudio test agent deploy (to same machine)
3. Run functional tests (the assembly shipped in 1)

The test run (and have the same mix of pass fail, skipped) but the test results can be browsed just fine with the web pages test links.
[image: Test results showing failures in build definition results]

**Results after hammering the same test into a different environment to see how that behaves...**

Well, same 3 steps (targeting the same test machine) in a different environment works as expected - same mix of results, but view shows results without errors.
To be clear this is a different (pre-existing) environment in the same release definition, targeting the same test PC. It would seem the issue is somehow tied to that specific environment. So how do I fix that then?

*So next step, clone the failing environment and see what happens.* Back later with the results.

Comment: What's the result if you run the test with the same settings in TFS build definition instead of release?  Did you get the same result: `Most pass, some are not run, and a few fail.` and you could not view the detail result of the failed test case.

Comment: Same tests on same machine have same test results, but show correctly in tests view after build.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the test with same settings in build definition instead of release. This could narrow down if the issue is  related to your tests or task configuration.

Double check you have use the right settings of related tasks. You could refer related tutorial for Selenium test in MSDN: [Get started with Selenium testing in a continuous integration pipeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium)

Try to run the same release in another environment.

Also go through your log files to see if there are some related info for troubleshooting.

Comment: I will try that when I can find a moment and update the question with the results.

Comment: Added the steps to copy the test assemblies to a machine, install the test agent, and run the tests on said machine. This all works as expected. The issue seems to be related to being in an RM definition. Will write up discoveries in update to question in a while.